# SQL How to sort by "Ranges"

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers, range

I am currently using a database with different entries like dates, names, but also one column with time "ranges". This basically means that there can be a definite number like "10" in this cell, but also a value like "10-15" or "5-10".
So what I want to do here is to sort them by an "average" value ((Lowest+Highest)/2). So in case of the 3 mentioned values it should be
5-10
10
10-15
I am wondering if it is possible to embed this into the SQL statement in some way.
And if it is not possible, I'd like to know the easiest way to implement it otherwise.

Right now I am putting the $SQL_statement together via several conditions, then putting everything into $resultset which is then used with "while". Here are some snippets:

```
$resultset=mysql_query($SQL_statement);
while ($currententry=mysql_fetch_array($resultset))
{
    echo $currententry['Platform'];
    echo $currententry['PlaytimeInH']."h";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `substring_index()` and arithmetic:

```
order by (substring_index(col, '-', 1) + 0 +
          substring_index(col, '-', -1) + 0
         ) / 2
```

The division by 2 is unnecessary, but you do specify the average in your question.

Note that the above will work even if `col` has no hyphen in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select with a case when  clause  in order by

```
select col1, col2, cole 
from  your_table 
order by case 
         when your_column  = '5-10'  then 1 
         when your_column  = '10-15'  then 2
         when your_column  = '15-20'  then 3 
         else 4
         end
```

Comment: Thanks. But there are over 600 entries in this database with all kinds of variations. So doing it like that would defat the purpose of the database as I would completely have to order it manually.